# Convert one column to two column based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table look like this:

```
TagName          DateTime        value
HA_06_ON    2020-07-07 08:52:14    1
HA_06_ON    2020-07-07 09:01:42    0
HA_06_ON    2020-07-07 09:02:17    1
HA_06_ON    2020-07-07 09:32:55    0
HA_06_ON    2020-07-07 09:33:21    1
HA_06_ON    2020-07-07 09:35:02    0
HA_06_ON    2020-07-07 09:35:27    1 
HA_06_ON    2020-07-07 09:35:44    0
HA_06_ON    2020-07-07 10:10:32    1
HA_06_ON    2020-07-07 10:10:40    0
```

I want to convert this table into this base on value (value = 1 ==> startTime, value = 0 ==> EndTime).

```
TagName        StartTime                EndTime
HA_06_ON   2020-07-07 08:52:14      2020-07-07 09:01:42
HA_06_ON   2020-07-07 09:02:17      2020-07-07 09:32:55
....
```

I have tried to use case when on select statement but return null on each column like this

```
TagName           StartTime            EndTime
HA_06_ON      2020-07-07 08:57:07       NULL
HA_06_ON            NULL        2020-07-07 09:01:42
HA_06_ON      2020-07-07 09:02:17       NULL
HA_06_ON            NULL        2020-07-07 09:32:55
HA_06_ON      2020-07-07 09:33:21       NULL
HA_06_ON            NULL        2020-07-07 09:35:02
```

Comment: That's not converting one column to two, this is a gaps-and-islands problem - you're trying to find the start/end values for the island specified by `value`. `Gaps & islands` is the actual name of that category of problems. You can google for it to find solutions. In this case, `SUM (value) OVER(partition by TagName ORDER BY DateTime)` will give you an IslandID you can use for grouping and extracting the `MIN(DateTime)` and `MAX(DateTime)` value. `SUM OVER` returns a running total of `value`. Given `value`'s ... values that ends up being an incrementing `Island` ID

Comment: You can't group over a calculated column though, so all this should be wrapped in a CTE, eg `with islands AS (SELECT ... SUM() ... As IslandID FROM..) select TagName,MIN(DateTimeOffset),MAX(DateTime) from islands GROUP BY TagName,IslandID`

Comment: With the order always be 1 -> 0 -> 1 -> 0 -> ... ? Could you have 1 -> 0 -> 0 -> 1? What happens then?

Comment: [Here is a good place to read about Gaps and Islands](https://livebook.manning.com/book/sql-server-mvp-deep-dives/chapter-5)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you so much for your help!!! I have search the gaps and islands and be able to solve my problem!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because I didn't see the `sum() over` option

**Example**

```
Select TagName
      ,StartTime = min(DateTime)
      ,EndTime   = max(DateTime)
 From ( 
        Select *
              ,Grp = sum(value) over (partition by TagName order by DateTime) 
         From @YourTable
      ) A
 Group By TagName,Grp
```

**Returns**

```
TagName     StartTime                   EndTime
HA_06_ON    2020-07-07 08:52:14.000     2020-07-07 09:01:42.000
HA_06_ON    2020-07-07 09:02:17.000     2020-07-07 09:32:55.000
HA_06_ON    2020-07-07 09:33:21.000     2020-07-07 09:35:02.000
HA_06_ON    2020-07-07 09:35:27.000     2020-07-07 09:35:44.000
HA_06_ON    2020-07-07 10:10:32.000     2020-07-07 10:10:40.000
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have no grouping column here, we have to make an assumption: We can process your data assuming that if we order by date, the 1's and 0's will alternate. Otherwise there is no solution, since we don't know how to correlate the 1's with the 0's.

Given that we can assume this ordering, we can use `lag()` or `lead()` to do this. Note that this assumes you start with 1, and every 1 has a corresponding 0. If the last 1 does not have a corresponding 0, then EndTime will be null for that row.

```
select  u.TagName, 
        u.StartTime, 
        u.EndTime 
from    (
        select  TagName, 
                StartTime = [DateTime] ,
                EndTime   = lead([DateTime], 1) over
                            (
                                partition by TagName
                                order by [Datetime] asc
                            ), 
                value 
        from t
        ) u
where   u.value = 1
```

Comment: You need to partition by `tagname`.

Comment: True, I should not assume a single TagName.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to approach this.  If I assume that the values are perfectly interleaved, one method is aggregation:

```
select tagname, min(datetime) as starttime, max(datetime) as endtime
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by tagname, value order by datetime) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by tagname, seqnum;
```